# Naming calculated columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to name columns created from the output of a function in data.table?

I want to get regression estimates from some data, so my code looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(expand.grid(x = 1:10, t = letters[1:4]))
DT[, y := rnorm(10), by = t]

# Function to get estimates and standard error for
# each regressor.
ExtractLm <- function(model) {
    a <- summary(model)
    return(list(rownames(a$coefficients),
                a$coefficients[, 1],
                a$coefficients[, 2]))
}

DT.regression <- DT[, ExtractLm(lm(x ~ y)), by = t]
```

The problem here is that `DT.regression` has ugly names (V1, V2, V3). One solution would be to modify the function `ExtractLm()` so that it returns a named list, but I think this is not very flexible since it wouldn't allow me to use different names in another situation. Or course, I can always rename columns after the fact, but that's not very elegant.

I tried to use `DT[, c("regressor", "estimate", "se") = ExtractLm(lm(x ~ y)), by = t]` and many variants and it doesn't work. I've been re-reading the docs but I've only found that kind of syntax when creating new columns with `:=`, which is not aplicable to this case. Is there a way to use a similar syntax to do this?

Comment: Not specific to data.table, what about: `DT[, setNames(ExtractLm(lm(x ~ y)), c("regressor", "estimate", "se")), by = t]`

Comment: Yeah, it works. Not the most beautiful syntax there is, but I take it!

Comment: Fyi, with `verbose=TRUE`, you'll see data.table complaining about inefficiency coming from names per group. Probably not a big deal here, though.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Fixed with `unname(a$coefficients[, 1])`.